# Xcode, testing a method, XCTAssert will not recognise true

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've created a unit test for a method, this is the method I'm testing.

```
- (BOOL)isValidCoords:(NSString*)strCoords{
    NSArray* mutarrReadLines = [strCoords componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    if(mutarrReadLines.count != 3){
        NSLog(@"Coord failed count test,%@",strCoords);
    return false;
    }
    else if([mutarrReadLines[0] doubleValue] > 89 || [mutarrReadLines[0] doubleValue] < -89){
        NSLog(@"Coord failed lat test,%@",strCoords);
        return false;
    }
    else if([mutarrReadLines[1] doubleValue] > 179 || [mutarrReadLines[1] doubleValue] < -179){
        NSLog(@"Coord failed lon test,%@",strCoords);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically, it returns false if the parameter is not a valid coordinate.

This is my test:

```
- (void)testIsArrayOfValidCoordsWithValidCoords
{
    NSString *input = @"1;1;2015";
    BOOL actualResult = [GPSCoordsTable isValidCoords:input];
    XCTAssertTrue(actualResult == true);
}
```

I have tested that "1;1;2015" is a valid coord in the running program, and it works. I have even changed the isValidCoords method so that every return path is true. I have made it impossible for the return value to be false. Yet the test still fails and says that the return value wasn't true.

Comment: Objective-C uses `YES`/`NO` instead of `true`/`false`.  Also what happens if you use `XCTAssertTrue(actualResult);`?

Comment: Made both of those changes. Still failing.

It doesn't seem to differentiate between true/false and yes/no. Either way, it says the method returned 0 and it expected 1.

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  NSLog `actualResult`?  Add an NSLog to the `return true;` path and make sure it's hit?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. Turns out Xcode is a clown which presents you nonsensical error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it working. Turns out Xcode is a clown which presents you nonsensical error messages.

First problem: I was trying to call the method from a view controller that I forgot to initialise. Turns out that if you do that, it doesn't crash or fail to build, it just doesn't do anything.

Second, once I tried to initialise the view controller, I ended up getting weird errors about "symbols not available for X86-64" or something like that. The problem there ended up being that all my .m files had disappeared from the "Compile Sources" in the project settings.

Comment: Please add the solution to the problem, for future users that run into similar problems.

Comment: Ok, but I doubt anybody will ever have this problem.

Comment: You never know who might have a very similar situation as yours :)